# Reset Password Link For Firebase App Not Working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

so I have recently implemented a reset password feature in my App, which sends a email to the user with the reset password link. Something looking like this
`https://myfirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=XXXX&apiKey=XXXX&lang=en`
But then when I click on this link, the page freezes up and doesn't load at all. So then I thought maybe its caused due to API Restrictions to allow only certain domains which I preconfigure. So I went to fix it by adding the websites to the allowed sections in the "edit API key " section. But it still doesn't work. So is there any other setting that I need to change or add?:
[image: api key]

Comment: You just have to specify the domain name of your Firebase project and not any path so just `<project-id>.firebaseapp.com` is required. If that does not work, can you please check network tab in dev tools and share complete error message from there? It should show us what domain is not allowed to access the APIs.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hi there, the issue is Im not getting any response back. the network tab just shows that the request has been sent and there is no response. And this lack of response causes the page to look like it has freezen down, and there is a infinite loading of tab.

Comment: Do you know how I can reproduce the issue? Can you also share a screenshot of your network logs from browser dev tools (and the response of Firebase related requests)? Make sure all the requests are logged in it.

Comment: I think to reproduce this issue as far as my knowledge goes is the following: Create a new app, then add a API key restriction using Google Console for this app to only allow requests from certain domains/websites. At this point I could notice the above issue and thought maybe its due to permission denial. so I whitelisted the `myapp.firebaseapp.com` also in the  same place, but the issue continues to exist and doesn't go.

Comment: The network log just says "pending"

Comment: I can confirm I don't face can issues with restricting API key to my project's domain. _Which_ request shows status pending? It would be easier to figure out the issue if you could provide additional details. You can also [export the network log as HAR](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10358597?hl=en) share (after removing any sensitive info)

Comment: Hi there, this is strange, but after around 15mins it now gave the response as link expired. Then I requested for another password reset email and now it works like normal, how it was supposed to. Im definitely sure that this was not an issue with my ISP/Internet Connection as other more intensive apps like YT ran fine during this time

Comment: Again here, i tried this procedure with a "different user" this time and the issue is still persisting where it taking a very long time for the link to load

Comment: Please provide additional details mentioned in my previous comment or equivalent. There isn't enough information to reproduce this information.

Comment: Hi there, here's the reset link for a dummy account(https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=l8k38kY71R6thkvPGor9yyBfcfJdDuHTPuY4BY18NMsAAAGGIFNNWg&apiKey=AIzaSyDN8T7Pmw5e-LzmC3nAHEqI0Uk7FF7y6fc&lang=en)
i just tried it out on BrowserLing, and there it loads instantly. This means this has something to do with my Antivirus or ISP preventing the request from going through.

Comment: I get an expired link error with that one. If you think its anti virus then try with some other device.

Comment: Hi there, I have confirmed that this issue was due to some AntiVirus issue. The reset link works perfectly fine in other devices(tried on mobile). Thank you for your time

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue. You should post that as an answer in case someone faced this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please include `https://<app-name>.firebaseapp.com` as well.

Comment: Hi there, I have included both `https://myfirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com` and `myfirebaseapp.firebaseapp.com/*  ` but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Sometimes it takes few hours to reflect and start to work